# Seleccionar registro con mayor valor en un campo

Tags: sql, sql-server

EStoy haciendo una consulta en SQLServer donde requiero el registro de dias trabajados de x cantidad de empleados.

En los días en que estos están de Descanso, pueden trabajar obteniendo el día adicional.

La consulta que tengo me genera lo siguiente

```
id  cliente puesto  empleado    anno    mes dia turno
1   ACME    PUERTA  CORRECAMINOS    2016    6   1   001
1   ACME    PUERTA  CORRECAMINOS    2016    6   2   DESCANSO
1   ACME    BODEGA  CORRECAMINOS    2016    6   3   001
1   ACME    BODEGA  CORRECAMINOS    2016    6   4   001
1   ACME    PUERTA  CORRECAMINOS    2016    6   5   001
1   ACME    BODEGA  CORRECAMINOS    2016    6   6   001
1   ACME    BODEGA  CORRECAMINOS    2016    6   7   001
1   ACME    PUERTA  CORRECAMINOS    2016    6   8   001
1   ACME    BODEGA  CORRECAMINOS    2016    6   9   DESCANSO
2   ACME    BODEGA  CORRECAMINOS    2016    6   9   001 EXTRA
1   ACME    BODEGA  CORRECAMINOS    2016    6   10  001
1   ACME    BODEGA  CORRECAMINOS    2016    6   11  001
1   ACME    BODEGA  CORRECAMINOS    2016    6   12  001
1   ACME    BODEGA  CORRECAMINOS    2016    6   13  001
1   ACME    BODEGA  CORRECAMINOS    2016    6   14  001
1   ACME    BODEGA  CORRECAMINOS    2016    6   15  DESCANSO
```

El día 9 estuvo descansando pero laboró el dia como turno extra, lo que necesito es que no me salga duplicado el día 9 sino mostrar sólo el registro con el turno extra.

Mi consulta es algo así:

```
select id_registro, cliente,  puesto, empleado,
DATEPART(YEAR,fecha) anno, DATEPART(MONTH,fecha) mes, 
DATEPART(DAY,fecha) dia, turno
from programacion
where DATEPART(YEAR,fecha)=2016 and DATEPART(MONTH,fecha)=6
```

El resultado que necesito seria:

```
id  cliente puesto  empleado    anno    mes dia turno
1   ACME    PUERTA  CORRECAMINOS    2016    6   1   001
1   ACME    PUERTA  CORRECAMINOS    2016    6   2   DESCANSO
1   ACME    BODEGA  CORRECAMINOS    2016    6   3   001
1   ACME    BODEGA  CORRECAMINOS    2016    6   4   001
1   ACME    PUERTA  CORRECAMINOS    2016    6   5   001
1   ACME    BODEGA  CORRECAMINOS    2016    6   6   001
1   ACME    BODEGA  CORRECAMINOS    2016    6   7   001
1   ACME    PUERTA  CORRECAMINOS    2016    6   8   001
2   ACME    BODEGA  CORRECAMINOS    2016    6   9   001 EXTRA
1   ACME    BODEGA  CORRECAMINOS    2016    6   10  001
1   ACME    BODEGA  CORRECAMINOS    2016    6   11  001
1   ACME    BODEGA  CORRECAMINOS    2016    6   12  001
1   ACME    BODEGA  CORRECAMINOS    2016    6   13  001
1   ACME    BODEGA  CORRECAMINOS    2016    6   14  001
1   ACME    BODEGA  CORRECAMINOS    2016    6   15  DESCANSO
```

Intenté con MAX (id) pero no funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar una CTE:

```
WITH ProgramacionOrdered ([id_registro], cliente, puesto, empleado, anno, mes, dia, turno, num)
AS (SELECT 
    id_registro, cliente, puesto, empleado, DATEPART(YEAR, fecha), DATEPART(MONTH, fecha), DATEPART(DAY, fecha),
    turno, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cliente, puesto, empleado, fecha ORDER BY id_registro DESC)
FROM programacion)
SELECT id_registro, cliente, puesto, empleado, anno, mes, dia, turno
FROM ProgramacionOrdered WHERE num=1
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias. Me funcionó perfecto. Tardé en acomodarlo a mi consulta real, que era un poco mas compleja. Pero me fué de maravilla. :)